# Understanding .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm looking for help with understanding how a particular .htaccess file works.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here's what I think I understand so far:

Line 1: allow Apache to change urls based on certain rules?

Lines 2,3: Something about not accessing files and directories. However my browser has no trouble with accessing  `http://localhost/dev/can_i/yes_i_can.php`, so I don't think I'm understanding that correctly.

Line 4: I get that `^(.*)$`is a regular expression saying "beginning and ending with anything" but what exactly does this refer to? the whole url? Then it gets replaced by index.php with the expression appended. So why don't we get things like `localhost/index.php?url=localhost/index.php/whatever_came_after`?
Finally what does [L, QSA] do? I know QSA means "query string append" but not sure how it works.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this to enable apache mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
```

this two lines mean that if the file with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist, or the directory in the browser doesn't exist then procede to the rewrite rule below

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

RewriteCond basically means "execute the next RewriteRule only if this is true". The `!-l` path is the condition that the request is not for a link (! means not, `-l` means link)

The RewriteRule basically means that if the request is done that matches `^(.+)$` (matches any URL except the server root), it will be rewritten as index.php?url=$1 which means a request for ollewill be rewritten as index.php?url=olle.

`QSA` means that if there's a query string passed with the original URL, it will be appended to the rewrite (olle?p=1 will be rewritten as `index.php?url=olle&p=1`.

L means if the rule matches, don't process any more RewriteRules below this one.

For more complete info on this, follow the links above. The rewrite support can be a bit hard to grasp, but there are quite a few examples on stackoverflow to learn from.